Print all incoming headers in Azure API Manager
I am trouble shooting an inbound 3rd party service and I want to log all inbound headers.  As I dont know what headers I am receiving I cant use log analytics to capture headers.
I would like to use a mock response on APIM to print all inbound headers as a response message.
I have created the policy:
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="HostName" value="@{
            string [] HostNameHeader;
            
            context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Host", out HostNameHeader);    

            return HostNameHeader[0];
        }" />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" />
            <set-body>"@{context.Variables["HostName"]}"</set-body>
        </return-response>
        <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

My response message is returning the text "@{context.Variables["HostName"]}" rather than the the expected headers.

Policy shared by you will only provide you the header named Host present in inbound section. Here is the corrected policy but you will only get the value of header Host.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="HostName" value="@{
            string[] HostNameHeader;
            
            context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Host", out HostNameHeader);    

            return HostNameHeader != null && HostNameHeader.Length > 0 ? HostNameHeader[0] : null;
        }" />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" />
            <set-body>@{
                string hostName = context.Variables["HostName"] as string;
                return hostName != null ? hostName : "No Host Header Found";
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
        <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

Output-

To print all the inbound headers as a response message, you can use the below policy.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" />
            <set-body>@{
                string responseMessage = "Inbound Headers:\n";
                foreach(var header in context.Request.Headers)
                {
                    responseMessage += $"{header.Key}: {string.Join(", ", header.Value)}\n";
                }
                return responseMessage;
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
        <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

Output-

